# Docker bridge and order of Dockers startup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bridge

I am having 10 Dockers running in production environment all are talking to each other using a docker bridge that I defined, everything works great till you restart the production server. Post restart the bridge IP address to docker containers changes and Dockers are no longer able to communicate with each other. As the IP addresses are hard-coded in the configuration of a docker that handles communication with other Dockers. As a result I have to reconfigure this docker on every weekend.

Wanted to know if there's any way I can eliminate this manual step and may be map the Dockers based on their name or something. Currently thinking of using docker-compose file but not sure how I can configure the IP address, as the bridge IP addresses are not known while building the file.

Any help in resolving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: use hostname instead of private container ip?

Answer (score 0):

Containers can communicate using the container name instead of IP within the local bridge. Try updating the config to communicate using the container names. To ensure that right container names are used in config, make sure that you have the right container names assigned explicitly.

Official docker documentation for reference: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge

Comment: Thank you for your response @akazuko so in my application's env file (which is dockerized) instead of mentioning http://172.17.0.X you are saying I can use <container name> ? if so can you point me to a code sample of the same.

Comment: From the official documentation: “ Imagine an application with a web front-end and a database back-end. If you call your containers web and db, the web container can connect to the db container at db, no matter which Docker host the application stack is running on”

Comment: Ok, Let me try that and will update here if I face any difficulties